# VB “Financial.Rate” equivalent in Java or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, vb.net

There is a built in function from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly. 
I can use it in VB like this:

```
APR = (Rate(TotPmts, -Payment, PVal, FVal, PayType, Guess) * 12) * 100
```

My current project is in Java or Javascript and I need to use this function.

Answers on the web say just add the namespace and assembly and use the same in Java or Javascript

So how can I use use Financial.
Rate in Java (or perhaps even porting the source code to it)?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're asking two questions (how to do this in 1) Java and 2) C#) then please ask two different questions. An answer on SO has to answer the entire question, not half if it, but the solution in Java and C# is likely to be entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

In a C# project(or other .NET projects), just simply add `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` as a reference into your project, you can use [Financial.Rate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.rate(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code, don't forget to add the namespace `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` It's very easy because all .NET languages (C#/VB/etc) uses the CIL (Common Intermediate Language), so the `.dll` files compiled from different languages can be shared.

In a Java project, things are quite different. You need to use JNA(Java Native Access). See [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).